# How to convert SOAP request to HTTP GET?

Tags: http, soap, get, wso2

I am trying to construct an REST service query parameters from an incoming SOAP request, and I need GET mode request(`doGet:http://localhost:8888/XMPPService/recieveMsg?accessId=admin&accessSeq=admin&accessPwd=admin`).
I use property REST_URL_POSTFIX. 
My config is:

```
<target>
      <inSequence>
           <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" value="?accessId=accessId&accessSeq=accessSeq" scope="axis2" />
           <send>
              <endpoint>
                <address uri="http://localhost:8888/XMPPService/recieveMsg" >   
              </endpoint>
           </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full" />
         <send />
      </outSequence>
    </target>
    <publishWSDL key="XMPPService_wsdl" />
```

But is also POST mode request, it calls doPost method, not GET mode request.
The receive message is also:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <p:XMPPService xmlns:p="http://iag.sdp.coship.com/xmpp/">
            <accessId>admin</accessId>
            <accessSeq>admin</accessSeq>
            <accessPwd>admin</accessPwd>
        </p:XMPPService>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on what you are trying. From my understanding, you are trying to construct an REST service query parameters from an incoming SOAP request.

If that is the case use REST_URL_POSTFIX property to set the query parameters.

I have written this [post](http://vvratha.blogspot.com/2011/11/invoking-restful-service-via-wso2esb.html) which may help you.

Comment: Thanks, Ratha, that's very kind of you. Yes, I am trying to construct an REST service query parameters from an incoming SOAP request, and I need GET mode request(doGet:http://localhost:8888/XMPPService/recieveMsg?accessId=admin&accessSeq=admin&accessPwd=admin).
I use property REST_URL_POSTFIX. 
But is also POST mode request, it calls doPost method, not GET mode request.

Comment: Im still not clear, If you want to construct such GET url, you can use that REST_URL_POSTFIX property to construct the resource pattern. That is waht mentioned in the blog. For your URL, you need pass accessID/seq/passwd.. Pick them from incoming SOAP request, and use string concat using xpath and assign that to REST_URL_POSTFIX property. For REST_URL_POSTFIX, you can assign value(which is a string) or expression.(which is xpath)

Comment: eg: <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX "
                         expression="concat(xx,yy,zz)"/>